# Friends system bug (laravel 5.2)(not getting desired view)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, relationship

when two users become friend, it is shown

you and `{{$user->getNameOrUsername()}}` are friends (working fine)

but it is shown on every profile and I want that it is only shown on those two users (which are friends)

if you need any other file or function ,tell me.

my view :

```
 @if(Auth::user()->hasFriendRequestPending($user))
    <p>waiting for {{$user->getNameOrUsername()}} to accept ur reqst </p>
 @elseif(Auth::user()->hasFriendRequestReceived($user))
    <a href="{{route('friend.accept',['username' => $user->username])}}" class="btn btn-primary" >Accept frnd reqst</a>
 @elseif(Auth::user()->isFriendsWith($user))
    <p>you and {{$user->getNameOrUsername()}} are friends</p>
 @else
    <a href="{{route('friend.add',['username' => $user->username])}}" class="btn btn-primary">Add as friend</a>
 @endif
```

friend controller :

```
    class FriendController extends Controller
{
   public function getIndex(){

    $friends=Auth::user()->friends();
    $requests = Auth::user()->friendRequests();
    return view('friends',['friends'=>$friends,'requests' => $requests]);
   }

   public function getAdd($username){


        $user = User::where('username', $username)->first();
        if(!$user){
            return redirect()->route('home')->with('info', 'That user could not be found');
        }
        if(Auth::user()->id === $user->id){
            return redirect()->route('home');
        }
        if(Auth::user()->hasFriendRequestPending($user) || $user->hasFriendRequestPending(Auth::user())) {
            return redirect()->route('myplace', ['username' => $user->username])
            ->with('info', 'Friend Request already pending.');
        }
        if(Auth::user()->isFriendsWith($user)) {
            return redirect()->route('myplace', ['username' => $user->username])
            ->with('info', 'You are already friends.');
        }
        Auth::user()->addFriend($user);
        return redirect()->route('myplace', ['username' => $user->username])
            ->with('info', 'Friend Request Sent.');
    }

    public function getAccept($username){
        $user = User::where('username', $username)->first();

        if(!$user) {
            return redirect()->route('home')->with('info', 'That user can not be found.');
        }
        if(!Auth::user()->hasFriendRequestReceived($user)) {
            return redirect()->route('home');
        }
        Auth::user()->acceptFriendRequest($user);
        return redirect()->route('myplace', ['username' => $user->username])
            ->with('info', 'Friend Request accepted.');
       }
    }
```

postcontroller:

```
public function getmyplace($username)
{
    $user = User::where('username', $username)->first();
    if(!$user)
        abort(404);

    $posts=Post::where(function($query) use($user)
     {
         $query->where('user_id',$user->id)
            ->orWhere('target_id',$user->id);
    })
    ->orderBy('created_at','desc')->get();


    //User::find(Auth::id())->posts;

    //$posts=Post::orderBy('created_at','desc')->get();

    $accounts=Account::orderBy('updated_at','desc')->limit(1)->get();

    return view('myplace',['user'=>$user,'posts'=>$posts,'accounts'=>$accounts]);
}
```

user model functions:

```
public function getNameOrUsername(){
    return $this->getName() ?: $this->username;
}

public function getFirstNameOrUsername() {
    return $this->firstname ?: $this->username;
}
public function friendsOfMine(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'friends', 'user_id', 'friend_id');
}
public function friendOf(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'friends', 'friend_id', 'user_id');
}
public function friends(){
    return $this->friendsOfMine()->wherePivot('accepted', true)->get()
            ->merge($this->friendOf()->wherePivot('accepted', true)->get());
}
public function friendRequests(){
    return $this->friendsOfMine()->wherePivot('accepted', false)->get();
}
public function friendRequestsPending() {
    return $this->friendOf()->wherePivot('accepted', false)->get();
}
public function hasFriendRequestPending(User $user) {
    return (bool) $this->friendRequestsPending()->where('id', $user->id)->count();
}
public function hasFriendRequestReceived(User $user){
    return (bool) $this->friendRequests()->where('id', $user->id)->count();
}
public function addFriend(User $user){
    $this->friendOf()->attach($user->id);
}

public function deleteFriend(User $user){
    $this->friendOf()->detach($user->id);
}

public function acceptFriendRequest(User $user) {
    $this->friendRequests()->where('id', $user->id)->first()->pivot
    ->update([
        'accepted'=>true,
    ]);
}
public function isFriendsWith(User $user) {

    return (bool) $this->friends()->where('id',$user->id)->count();
}
```

Comment: What is $user ? Which controller function returns the view you posted? Please also provide the three user model functions you used.

Comment: $user is the one on whose profile i am on.

Comment: postcontroller's getmyplace returns the view

Comment: Please also provide the user model functions like hasFriendRequestPending

Comment: @FrankProvost provided :)

Comment: On first sight I cannot see something dramatically wrong - You can actually remove the friend controller from the question, since it doesnt seem relevant. Can you maybe add a little bit more regarding the desired behaviour? Maybe give examples on what User A should see When visiting user B's profile (A friend with B) and what he should see on user C's profile (not friends) and finally, what he actually now sees ( so the problem )

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121812/discussion-between-yash-chaudhary-and-frank-provost).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the chat https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121812 the problem is that you return $user from the controller

```
 return view('myplace',['user'=>$user,'posts'=>$posts,'accounts'=>$accounts]);
```

And then later within the view loop through a userse friends

```
@foreach(Auth::user()->friends() as $user) {

}
```

By this the $user variable returned from the controller is overwritten.

Simply renaming $user resolves the problem